# how to pass facebook object in intent?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I would like to implement an android app requires facebook login in the beginning. As I declare the facebook object in main activity and want to invoke facebook.authorize in another activity, but I can't put the facebook object to intent, is there other way to achieve this?

Here is the flow:
When the app is first opened, a main activity is opened. It will then check if the access token is set, if no, a new activity is started to let user login. In that activity there are some login option and a login button. If user press the login button, facebook api is called to do the login.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar method that is used in the official facebook/android examples.
Using the [SessionStore](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/SessionStore.java) you can do something like:

First activity:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("APP_ID");
if (!SessionStore.restore(facebook, this)) {
    // start the other activity for authentication
}
```

Second activity:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("APP_ID");
facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        SessionStore.restore(facebook, this)
    }
    ...
});
```